# React component from constant

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have js file with routes for my menu.

menuConstant.js

```
import PeopleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/People'
export const routers = [
  {
    title: 'Clients',
    to: '/clients',
    icon: PeopleIcon, // doesn't work
    items: [
      { itemTitle: 'Invoice', itemTo: '/invoice' },
      { itemTitle: 'Test', itemTo: '/test' }
    ]
  },
  { title: 'systems', to: '/systems' },
  { title: 'system accesses', to: '/system-accesses' }
]
```

I'am using material ui List and ListItem for render menu. How can i add material ui Icons in constant file that will render in menu?

Menu.jsx

```
export const ResponsiveDrawerItem = ({ className, title, to, icon }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem className={className} component={NavLinkRouter} button activeClassName='Mui-selected' exact to={to}>
      <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon> // icon from constant not working
      <ListItemText primary={title} />
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your material icon should be called like a component, and you should rename to titlecase icon as well:

```
export const ResponsiveDrawerItem = ({ className, title, to, icon: Icon }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem className={className} component={NavLinkRouter} button activeClassName='Mui-selected' exact to={to}>
      <ListItemIcon><Icon /></ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={title} />
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```